# Symfony2 formbuilder - entity readonly field as label

Tags: php, symfony

Is there any possibility in symfony2 to display a readonly-field of  an entity as a label rather than a text field or whatever?

I am currently using the following code, but using a disabled text field does not feel very sophisticated:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('readonlyfield', 'text', array('property_path' => 'readonlyfield.displayString','disabled' => true));
        $builder->add('editablefield', 'textarea');
    }
```

I am using symfony 2.4.4..

EDIT:

I am using this form type from within another form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('mySubEntities', 'collection', array('type' => new MySubEntryType()));
        $builder->add('save_to_db',  'submit', array('label' => 'Submit'));
    }
```

twig file:

```
 {{ form_start(form) }}
    {% for row in form.mySubEntities %}
        <li>
        <ul>
        <table>
        <tr><td>{{ form_label(row.readonlyfield) }} </td><td>{{ form_widget(row.readonlyfield) }}</td></tr>     
        <tr><td>{{ form_label(row.editablefield) }}</td><td> {{ form_widget(row.editablefield) }}</td></tr>
        </table>
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}


{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Why you need this ? If you want to display a property of the entity you are editing just use that to display the value `{{ entity.readonlyfield }}`

Comment: Basically the answer is: no. But take a look at [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html)

Comment: @Hpatoio It is a nested form. I have a collection of multiple of these entities (collection type) which I do want to submit with a single click, so I do not have access to the concrete (sub-) entities from within my twig-file (or at least do not know how to do this).

Comment: @seb You can access value in form using `{{ form.vars.value.yourfield }}` You have a nested/collection so try `{{ row.vars.value.readonlyfield }}`

Comment: @Hpatoio Works like a charm. Turn the comment into an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access value in form using `{{ form.vars.value.yourfield }}`.

You have a nested/collection so use `{{ row.vars.value.yourfield }}`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just render the entity property in your template instead of making it part of a form? You could make your own FieldType but that's not what I recommand. If you want the value to be displayed as a form like file I would use the readonly property.