# Symfony2 Embed form on multiple entities

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.5

I have 3 entities
**User**

```
class User extends BaseUser
{    
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserPathologie", mappedBy="user")
     */ 
    protected $userPathologies;
}
```

**Pathologie**

```
class Pathologie
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserPathologie", mappedBy="pathologie")
     */ 
    protected $userPathologies;
}
```

**UserPathologie**

```
class UserPathologie
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="userPathologies")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pathologie", inversedBy="userPathologies")
     */ 
    protected $pathologie;

     /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="atteint", type="boolean")
     */
    private $atteint;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cause", type="text")
     */
    private $cause;

}
```

Then, on the User form, I want to have the list of all "Pathologies" with the checkbox "atteint" and textarea "cause".

ex:

--label-- Pathologies --/label--

Pathologie A : Yes/No  -  Textarea cause

Pathologie B : Yes/No  -  Textarea cause

Pathologie C : Yes/No  -  Textarea cause

Pathologie D : Yes/No  -  Textarea cause

Pathologie E : Yes/No  -  Textarea cause

I proceed like below but the inconvenient is that each line should be added dynamically with javascript and the "pathologies" are in a select field.

**in UserRegiterType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{   

    $builder
        ->add('userPathologies', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new UserPathologieType(), 
            'label' => false, 
            'allow_add' => true,
        ));
}
```

**And in UserPathologieType, I have**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{   

    $builder        
        ->add('pathologie')
        ->add('atteint', 'checkbox', array(
            'label' => false,
            'required' => false, 
        ))
        ->add('cause', 'textarea', array(
            'label' => 'Cause', 
            'required' => false, 
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid `patologies` in select field override the widget for the field

```
{% block pathologie_widget %}
    <b>{{ value }}</b>
{% endblock %}
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming for details about for theming

Or depending on how you are rendering your collection you can also take this way:
[Symfony2 formbuilder - entity readonly field as label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24950601/symfony2-formbuilder-entity-readonly-field-as-label/24953112#24953112)

To have all pathologies connected to a new user just add them in the `__construct` of `User`

```
public function __construct() {

   // get all phatologies

   foreach ($allPhatologies as UserPathologie) {
       $this->userPathologies->add(new UserPathologie());
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! But instead of putting it in the constructor, I put it in the controller in order to get all pathologies

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did to get it work

First add `cascade={"persist"}` to the OneToMany relation in User to persist automatically the user pathologies

```
Class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Myapp\UserBundle\Entity\UserPathologie", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     */ 
    protected $userPathologies;
}
```

Then, add all pathologies to the new entity as @Hpatoio suggested

```
private function createRegisterForm(User $entity)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $pathologies =  $em->getRepository("MyappUserBundle:Pathologie")->findAll();

    //Loop all pathologies
    foreach($pathologies as $patho) {
        $up = new UserPathologie();
        $up->setPathologie($patho);
        $up->setUser($entity);
        $up->setAtteint(false);

        //Add each pathologie to the User entity
        $entity->getUserPathologies()->add($up);
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserRegisterType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('register_user'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    return $form;
}
```

And in the twig template, I used again a loop to get the expected result

```
{% for up in form.userPathologies%}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ up.pathologie.vars.full_name }}" id="{{ up.pathologie.vars.id }}" value="{{ up.pathologie.vars.value }}" />
    <p class="line"><label>{{ up.vars.value.pathologie }}</label>{{ form_widget(up.atteint) }}</p>
    <p class="line">{{ form_row(up.cause) }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```