# Persisiting Many-to-Many with extra field in sonata admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Multimedia, Gallery and GalleryMultimedia.

Both Multimedia and Gallery have a One-to-Many relationship with GalleryMultimedia which holds multimedia_id, gallery_id and position.

In my MultimediaAdmin, I added list of Galleries as below:

```
->with('Thematic Galleries')
            ->add('gallery', 'entity', array(
            'class'         => 'ACME\MyBundle\Entity\Gallery',
            'property'      => 'name',
            'multiple'      => true,
            'expanded'      => true,
            'mapped' => false,))
        ->end()
```

Now I am stuck at persisiting the selected Gallery as a GalleryMultimedia object. In my Multimedia Model, I have the function below which I would love to pass the GalleryMultimedia object for persisiting but just can't figure out how.

```
public function setGalleries($galleries)
{
   if (count($galleries) > 0) {
       foreach ($galleries as $gallery) 
        {
            $this->addGallery($gallery);
        }
   }
    return $this;
}
```

Out of desparation, I added the following code in my MultimediaAdmin.php

```
public function prePersist($multimedia)
{
    $this->preUpdate($multimedia);
}

public function preUpdate($multimedia)
{
    $multimedia->setFiles($multimedia->getFiles());
    $this->saveGalleries($multimedia);
}

public function saveGalleries($multimedia)
{
    $galleryies = $this->getForm()->get('gallery')->getData();
    $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
    $em = $container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $existing_arr = array();
    $existing = $em->getRepository('ACMEMyBundle:GalleryMultimedia')->findBy(array('multimedia' => $multimedia));
    $gals = array();
    foreach($existing as $exist)
    {
        $existing_arr[] = $exist->getGallery()->getId();
    }
    foreach($galleryies as $gallery)
    {
        if(in_array($gallery->getId(),$existing_arr))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            $gm = new \ACME\MyBundle\Entity\GalleryMultimedia();
            $gm->setGallery($gallery);
            $gals[] = $gm;
            $multimedia->setGalleries($gals);
        }

    }
}
```

Can someone please assist my poor soul?

Comment: This approach may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137298/symfony2-embed-form-on-multiple-entities/26138814

Comment: I've looked at briefly but couldn't make much out of it but maybe because I was on phone. Thanks for trying out to help

Comment: Seen it, it doesn't really assist in my situation. I already have the whole list on my form I just need to persist galleries selected when creating multimedia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by making the persisting in postPersist like this

```
public function postPersist($multimedia)
{
    $this->postUpdate($multimedia);
}
public function postUpdate($multimedia)
{
    $this->saveGalleries($multimedia);
}
```

Hope this will help someone out there

Answer (score 0):

My way of doing it with objects:

```
public function preUpdate($object)
{
    $this->updateCountries($object);
}

public function updateCountries(\AppBundle\Entity\Product $object){
    $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
    $em = $container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $form_countries = $this->getForm()->get('Country')->getData();
    //form_countries is a Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
    $object_countries = $object->getCountries();
    //object_countries is a collection of \AppBundle\Entity\CountryProduct
    $list = array();
    foreach($object_countries as $country){
        if(!$form_countries->contains($country->getCountry())){
            //remove objects not in the form
            $em->remove($country);
        } else {
            //save the others to not re add them
            $list[] = $country->getCountry();
        }
    }
    foreach($form_countries as $country){
        if(!in_array($country, $list)){
            //add everyone in the form but not in the list
            $countryProduct = new \AppBundle\Entity\CountryProduct();
            $countryProduct->setProduct($object);
            $countryProduct->setCountry($country);
            $countryProduct->setValuation(1);
            $em->persist($countryProduct);
        }
    }
    $em->flush();
}
```

Comment: The first part of this should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Until then, please use answers only for standalone answers to the question.